# discord.py: command_prefix not parsed at runtime

Tags: python, discord.py

I wrote a bot with `discord.Client` but then ported it to `discord.ext.commands.Bot`. Since the later is a subclass of the first, I didn't need to change the code a lot. But I am unable to add commands to the bot.

The commands are ignored by the script. I initialized the `Bot` in the class `__init__`.

```py
class FooBot(discord.ext.commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            command_prefix='$',
            description='Your friendly neighborhood foobot! ',
            case_insensitive=True
        )
        super().add_command('bar')
```

I added the command using `@commands.command()` and then `add_command()`.

```py
@commands.command(name='bar', help='all the help you can get')
async def barFunc(ctx, *keywords):
    """ code here. """
```

Point to note is that the `on_message` function works. All the reactions are performed by the bot as normal.

```py
async def on_message(self, message):
    """ If constructs. """
```

I reckon that the messages goes to `on_message` and not to the constructor. **I can't figure out how to fix the class constructor?** I tried most of the combinations I can think of.

Comment: Maybe try changing `discod.ext.commands.Bot` to `discord.ext.commands.Bot`?

Comment: oh sorry that's just an error in writing the snippet...again sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, your on_message() event works, while the bot.commands are ignored.
There's a simple fix for this:

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)
    """ If constructs. """
```

Add that line to your on_message function, and the bot.commands should work.
Read the relevant documentation [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working).

Comment: Thanks for your help! It solved the issue. Couldn't find a solve anywhere else...even the docs were not helping.